# Forcing HTTP to HTTPS in httpd.conf giving blank page

Tags: ssl, https

I am using amazon ec2 instance and i have created a load balancer and uploaded my SSL certificate. I am able to hit https://www.example.com but i can also hit http://www.example.com .So i want to force all the http to HTTPS. How can i do this?

I have tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} http
  RewriteRule https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

But i get a blank page after restarting httpd.I can see the shortcut icon in the windows bar but i see a blank page. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL? It is simpler to use when compared to rewrites. If you must use rewrites, give https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS a try